# Conversion errors when returning a generic task from a method

Tags: c#, azure, generics, async-await, task

I've created a method to return a task from a query on an Azure mobile service.
But when I set the return type for the method, ie `Task` I get these errors pointing to the return part of the method:

I tried to remedy this by using a generic ILIst but it seems this can't be used for an async method.

Does anyone know how to correct the return type error in this method?

http://hastebin.com/ziwovovabe.tex

```
public async static Task<Item> QueryTable()
{
    var table = App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>();
    IMobileServiceTableQuery<Item> query = table.
        OrderBy(item => item.Id);

    Task<Item> items = new Task<Item>();
    items = await query.ToListAsync();

    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
await query.ToListAsync();
return items;
```

Attempts to return a `Task<List<Item>>`, while your return type is `Task<Item>`. Currently, your query is returning a collection, not a single item. The way it's currently implemented, the return type should be `Task<List<Item>>`:

```
public async static Task<List<Item>> QueryTable()
{
    var table = App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>();
    IMobileServiceTableQuery<Item> query = table.
        OrderBy(item => item.Id);

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: So your solution will return the collection, ie all the rows? If thats the case to invoke the method its just the following: ` Task<List<Item>> range = DatabaseModel.QueryTable();`  Or is that incorrect?

Comment: @BrianJ This will return your entire table ordered by `Id`. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The method returns a `Task<Item>`, but the asynchronous nature of the method handles the `Task<>` part for you.  Your code should just be returning an `Item`.  Maybe something like this?:

```
public async static Task<Item> QueryTable()
{
    var table = App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>();
    IMobileServiceTableQuery<Item> query = table.
        OrderBy(item => item.Id);

    return await query.ToListAsync();
}
```

However, `ToListAsync()` implies that this is returning a *collection* of items, not a single item.  Do you want to return a specific items from that collection?  Something like this?:

```
return await query.ToListAsync().Single(i => i.SomeProperty == someValue);
```

Or maybe you actually want to return the collection?  In which case maybe the return type should be a collection type.  Something like this:

```
public async static Task<IList<Item>> QueryTable()
{
    // ...
}
```

The point is that the `await` keyword creates the `Task<>` for you, all you need to do is return the type within the `Task<>`.

Comment: I'll test this tomorrow, I'm looking to return the complete collection of records from the database. How could I achieve that in this instance? I was under the impression that the query would store the collection.

Comment: @BrianJ: In that case the return type for the method should be a Task of a collection, as in the latter half of the answer.  Currently your method returns a single item, when it should be returning a list or enumerable of some kind.

Comment: Okay now I get ya, not very experienced with Tasks, so @Yuval Itzchakov answer above would return the list of records then?